# Disconnected Network Drive while connecting to windows using samba

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount, samba

We are facing an issue when we are trying to auto-mount a Samba share drive on a Windows EC2 instance. However, when we manually mount it or run the PowerShell script manually, it connects successfully. But when we automate the process using Task Scheduler or EC2 User Data, it doesn't connect and gives a "Disconnected Network Drive" error. I also checked the log of the user data, but it doesn't show any errors. The output file just says "The command completed successfully."

I have tried multiple solutions, such as editing the regedit settings for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanserver\parameters, and various mounting mechanisms, but none of them seem to work.

Please find the attached screenshot and PowerShell script that I am using for mounting. These PowerShell scripts work fine when I run them manually but do not work when run through automation methods like EC2 User Data and Task Scheduler.

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOTln.png)

user-date used in ec2 -

```
<powershell>

# Replace SERVER_IP, SHARE_NAME, USERNAME, and PASSWORD with your Samba server IP, share name, username, and password
$ServerIP = "sambaserverip"
$ShareName = "sambashare"
$Username = "username"
$Password = "password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $Password

# Mount the Samba share
New-PSDrive -Name "S" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$ServerIP\$ShareName" -Credential $Credential -Persist
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

another user data we tried to put in ec2 -

```
<powershell>
$drive_letter = "Z:"
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
net use $drive_letter "\\sambaserverip\sambashare" /user:$username $password
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odWRO.png)

Comment: You might receive a better response at: https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Please share all details **in text form**, not hidden in screenshots. Also, please share how your problem is related to programming